# When does QContextMenuEvent::reason() return QContextMenuEvent::Reason::Other?

Tags: qt, qt5

Can someone give me a real world example when `QContextMenuEvent::reason()` returns `QContextMenuEvent::Reason::Other`?

As of Qt5, the other enum values are:

- `QContextMenuEvent::Reason::Mouse`
- `QContextMenuEvent::Reason::Keyboard`

Docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcontextmenuevent.html#Reason-enum

I searched the whole Qt5 source base; I only found one use in a test case.

Comment: It could be used to indicate a programmatically opened context menu. Regarding its uses, I presume you mean this [test case](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/tests/auto/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem/tst_qgraphicsitem.cpp.html#5342). I have found it also [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/qt/WidgetApi/qgraphicswebview.cpp.html#389). It refers to [QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicssceneevent.cpp.html#876), where `reason` is initialized as `QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent::Other`.